# How to get the columns this cursor?

Tags: android, cursor

**I have this query for getting the non media files and I want to get the right column for the cursor but I can't get the column**

```
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    String[] projection = null;
    String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
    String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{mimeType};
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE; // unordered
    final Cursor allNonMediaFiles = managedQuery(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsPdf, sortOrder);
```

**I'm using this code to get the column and get all the data in it but it can't return the value**

```
    int file_column_index = allNonMediaFiles.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID);
    this.fileCount = allNonMediaFiles.getCount();
    this.pdf = new String[this.fileCount];
    this.pdfPath = new String[this.fileCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.fileCount; i++) {
        int pdfColumnIndex = allNonMediaFiles.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE);
        pdfPath[i] = allNonMediaFiles.getString(pdfColumnIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you do a *cursor.moveToFirst()* before traversing through cursor items.

Below code works fine

final Cursor allNonMediaFiles = (getBaseContext().getContentResolver()).query(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsPdf, sortOrder);

***allNonMediaFiles.moveToFirst();***

int file_column_index = allNonMediaFiles.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID);

...

Comment: I already figure it out by the way do you know how many non media files does android support like pdf txt xlxx

Comment: Hi I don't think there is a discrete list for Media/Non-Media files. Note that IANA (http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types) and APACHE (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/docs/conf/mime.types?view=annotate) maintains a list of all supported MIME types and we can use the same for querying.

Answer (score 1):

At last I figure it out all I need to do is to put move to first in my cursor

```
    final Cursor allNonMediaFiles = managedQuery(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsPdf, sortOrder);

    int file_column_index = allNonMediaFiles.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID);
    this.fileCount = allNonMediaFiles.getCount();
    this.pdf = new String[this.fileCount];
    this.pdfPath = new String[this.fileCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.fileCount; i++) {
        allNonMediaFiles.moveToFirst();
        pdfPath[i] = allNonMediaFiles.getString(1);
    }
```